# Correct way of including JQuery resources in custom TagLib in Grails

Tags: jquery, grails, taglib, custom-tag

I am making a custom TagLib for DateTime picker in grails. The code is as follows :

```
class jqueryDateTimePickerTagLib {

def dateTimePicker = {attrs, body ->
    def out = out
    def name = attrs.name    //The name attribute is required for the tag to work seamlessly with grails
    def id = attrs.id ?: name
    def value = attrs.value ?: new Date().format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")


    //Create input data text field for contaning Date Time string
    out.println "<input type=\"text\" name=\"${name}\" id=\"${id}\" value=\"${value}\" ><img id=\"${id}opencalender\" src=\"${resource(dir:'images', file:'calendar_btn.png')}\"></input>"

    // Adding Resources
    out.println "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"${resource(dir:'css', file:'jquery.datetimepicker.css')}\" />"
    out.println "<script src=\"${resource(dir:'js/jquery', file:'jquery.js')}\"></script>"
    out.println "<script src=\"${resource(dir:'js/jquery/ui', file:'jquery.datetimepicker.js')}\"></script>"

    // java script code 
    out.println "<script>"
    out.println "\$('#${id}').datetimepicker({"

    out.println "});"
    out.println "\$('#${id}opencalender').click(function(){"
    out.println "\$('#${id}').datetimepicker('show');"
    out.println "});"

    out.println "</script>"
}
}
```

The problem occurs where I am adding JQuery file resources. When this custom DateTime picker included two times in a GSP form, causes multiple declaration of JQuery resources for each include. 
I saw some examples of TagLibs, in those TagLibs, JQuery file resources are added in different def, as follows :

```
def resources = { attrs ->

    String style = attrs.style ? "${attrs.remove('style')}" : null;
    String theme = attrs.theme ? "css/${attrs.remove('theme')}.css" : "css/tiger.css";
    String lang = attrs.lang ? "calendar-${attrs.remove('lang')}.js" : "calendar-en.js";

    if(style) {
        out << "<style type='text/css'>@import url(${style});</style>"
    } else {
        out << "<style type='text/css'>@import url(${resource(dir:pluginContextPath,file:theme)});</style>"
    }

    out << """
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:pluginContextPath,file:"js/calendar.js")}"></script>\n
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:pluginContextPath,file:"js/lang/$lang")}"></script>\n
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:pluginContextPath,file:"js/calendar-setup.js")}"></script>\n

           """
}
```

I also tried to include resources in above manner in my custom TagLib, but didnt get success. So please tell me the way for solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def init = {
    out << "<link rel=stylesheet href='${resource(dir:pluginContextPath + '/css',file:'ua-bootstrap.css')}'/>"
    out << "<link rel=stylesheet href='${resource(dir:pluginContextPath + '/css',file:'ua-bootstrap-responsive.css')}'/>"
    out << "<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>"
    out << "<script src='${resource(dir:pluginContextPath +'/js',file:'bootstrap.js')}'></script>"
}
```

Comment: @moskiteau.... Even After applying your suggestion, JQuery files are not including automatically in head of my GSP page.